# NSURLRequest -> NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was told that using the -> in that way will keep my UI ticking so it doesnt lock! and save doing `NSThread` / `NSOperationQueue`

Can someone help me with the syntax of how i would use that? Im basically downloading a image into a `UIImage*`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has not been my experience. I normally have to turn off the idle timer to prevent the device from locking:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

The NSURLConnection is already asynchronous, so there is no need to add it to an NSOperationQueue. Apple has a very [helpful and concise guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) that shows you how to use it.